# How to add unallocated storage to main partition in ubuntu

Tags: linux, partition

[image: This is how my partitions looks]

I tried many thing but couldn't merge them. How to add unallocated part to main partition without losing data?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing ubuntu to an usb stick and open ubuntu with try ubuntu from the usb. Then I am able to unmount the main partition and resize by adding on it the unnallocated part with gparted.